# Ошибка при создании FileInputStream при помощи FileDescriptor

Tags: java

Приветствую.
Мне необходимо на основе существующего потока записи в конкретный файл (FileOutputStream outputStream) - создать поток чтения из него.
Получаю дескриптор файла из outputStream и создаю поток чтения

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(outputStream.getFD().
```

При попытке чтения из файла (fileInputStream.read) вылетает исключение:'

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Отказано в доступе
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
```

При записи в данный файл посредством outputStream проблем не возникало, только при чтении через дескриптор. Кроме того, метод дескриптора fd.valid() - возвращает true. Помогите разобраться

Comment: Я подозреваю, что FileOutputStream открывает поток только для записи  и из него нельзя читать. Это, видимо, определяется handl'ом на уровне системы. Можно, наверное, обойти это с использованием временных файлов или посмотреть в сторону RandomAccessFile: docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: Но есть же специальная структура, FileDescriptor, которая специально предназначена для использования в том числе и с FileInputStream. В описании к 'new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor)' написано: "Creates a FileInputStream by using the file descriptor fdObj, which represents an existing connection to an actual file in the file system". Еще сказано: "If there is a security manager, its checkRead method is called with the file descriptor fdObj as its argument to see if it's ok to read the file descriptor. If read access is denied to the file descriptor a SecurityException is thrown."

Comment: Как же мне все-таки из существующего потока записи в файл получить поток чтения из него, при условии, что у меня есть только ссылка на этот поток, и я точно знаю, что этот поток валидный - запись данных в него осуществляется успешно?